# is Array.Copy only one dimension?

Tags: c#, .net

Quick sanity check.  Is Array.Copy for one dimensional arrays only, or can it handle more?

[.Net Framework Array.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.ARRAY.COPY%29;k%28COPY%29;k%28SOLUTIONITEMSPROJECT%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true)

---

When reading the specs I read it (probably wrongly) to mean that the match must occur on the second dimension.  ie. the source and destination indexes can be different, and we can specify the number of elements.

Okay, so lets hone in on "match".  For an array of rank 2 getting copied to another arry of rank 2, say 10x4 to 20x4, are we saying that we must match on dimensions one and two, or two only.  I *need* it to be on the second dimension only.

Is the only way to achieve this with a looping mechanism in .net.  If so, that's going to be a lot slower than a block copy.

---

Check this out:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var A = new int[2,4] {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2}};

        var B = new int[4,4];
        var C = new int[4, 4];

        Array.Copy(A, 0, B, 4, 8);

        Array.ConstrainedCopy(A, 0, C, 8, 8); // haven't noticed this method before.  Same behaviour though.


    }
```

Notice that we have to specify the correct starting point in a one dimensional view of the world.  I didn't expect this.

Comment: Did you even read the any of the method pages in the link you provided?

Comment: @Alastair Pitts: yes.  Please see updated question.  Currently looking at live code that works fine for arrays of rank 1, but not for rank 2 (or presumably more).  Hence the question.

Comment: the key is the reference to "end to end" on the docs.  It's the layout of each dimension end to end.  edited my answer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It supports single and multi-dimensional as long as the source and destination match.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4yx47a1.aspx

> The sourceArray and destinationArray parameters must have the same
>   number of dimensions.
>
> When copying between multidimensional arrays, the array behaves like a
>   long one-dimensional array, where the rows (or columns) are
>   conceptually laid end to end. For example, if an array has three rows
>   (or columns) with four elements each, copying six elements from the
>   beginning of the array would copy all four elements of the first row
>   (or column) and the first two elements of the second row (or c

EDIT:

Think of match in the way it lays out "end to end".  A two dimensional array is really just consecutive memory blocks - a 3 x 4 = 12 blocks.  When it copies, it's going to copy the layout - the end to end layout.  The key is the line where they say it's conceptually laid end to end.

Comment: Think I got there now (see code example in edit).  Think I was expecting slightly richer functionality.  I can work with this thought.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Quote from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4yx47a1.aspx):

> When copying between multidimensional arrays, the array behaves like a
>   long one-dimensional array, where the rows (or columns) are
>   conceptually laid end to end. For example, if an array has three rows
>   (or columns) with four elements each, copying six elements from the
>   beginning of the array would copy all four elements of the first row
>   (or column) and the first two elements of the second row (or column).

Answer (score 1):

From: [Copy Method (Array, Array, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4yx47a1.aspx)

> The sourceArray and destinationArray parameters must have the same
>   number of dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy from a single dimensional array to an array of arrays (which is kinda like a multi-dimensional array in usage), you just have to use `Array.Copy` in a loop. For example, I used this bit when trying to get a `BitmapData` array into something more logical, like a 2-dimensional array.

```
Dim bitmapData As Imaging.BitmapData = myBitmap.LockBits(New Rectangle(0, 0, myBitmap.Width, myBitmap.Height), Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, myBitmap.PixelFormat)

Dim size As Integer = Math.Abs(bitmapData.Stride) * bitmapData.Height
Dim data(size - 1) As Byte

Marshal.Copy(bitmapData.Scan0, data, 0, size)

Dim pixelArray(myBitmap.Height)() As Byte

'we have to load all the opacity pixels into an array for later scanning by column
'the data comes in rows
For y = myBitmap.Height - 1 To 0 Step -1
    Dim rowArray(bitmapData.Stride * 4) As Byte
    Array.Copy(data, y * bitmapData.Stride, rowArray, 0, bitmapData.Stride)
    pixelArray(y) = rowArray
Next
```